# How do I apply an image to background using inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, inline

I've tried this:

```
<div id="test" style="background:url(*Various image links*)>
</div>
```

But nothing shows.

How do I do it?

Comment: Set a size for the `div`.... Also close style.

Comment: Forget to do that in the question. after playing around in sandbox i found that the div needed a size for the image to show.

Comment: That is correct. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rvz3okj/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. Firstly, you need a height & width, unless you have content within the div, else it'll be sized at 0px by 0px. Secondly, you need to watch out for single vs double quotes. Here is working example:

```
<div id="test" style="background:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png'); height:100px; width:100px;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

also display:block or inline-block, with a size

```
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-image:.....;
```

Comment: You do not have to set `inline-block` for this to work or block for that matter. (`div` is `display: block` by default).

Comment: just an example, as often people may want divs to sit along side each other

Comment: The OP cannot put a background in a `div` and you think they understand your answer without any explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Provide width and height of div:

```
<div id="test" style="background:url(*Various image links*); width:60px; height:60px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Read my comment on the question, your answer is wrong.

Comment: When you answer a question you need to make it clear as to what the solution is. At the moment you didn't add the height and width to your demo code and the style still does not have a closing `"`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the apostrophes in the url() and set size to the `div`

suppose

```
style="background:url('images/a.jpg');"
```

should be

```
style="background:url(images/a.jpg);"
```

Comment: Read my comment on the question, your answer is wrong.

Comment: this is not wrong.though user should provide div sizes is true.

Comment: It is wrong as this will not display without a size being set. In the case of the OP only the height needs to be set as `div` is a block element giving it a width already. Your answer is **wrong**.

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
<body>

<div style="background-image:url('../../Images/flower.jpg');width:300px;height:234px">
The flowers are very beautiful.
</div>
```

and it's recommended to use `background-color`so in case the picture doesnt load there's a colorful page not blank.

Comment: you should use  background-color before background-image .